# Can't find where the memory leaks in python with tracemalloc & guppy & mem_top & pympler

Tags: python, memory-leaks

These four packages have detected that python occupies round 400MB, but when I use 'top -d 1', there shows that it takes almost 3GB! Is there a more precise way to find out where are memory leaks?

more infos as follows:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND   
15881 root      20   0 5206548   3.1g  32960 S   0.0   4.9 334:13.48 python3   


                        types |   # objects |   total size
============================= | =========== | ============
                         dict |      653590 |    234.98 MB
                          str |      791447 |    116.25 MB
  guppy.sets.setsc.ImmNodeSet |         895 |     47.54 MB
                          int |     1286323 |     36.75 MB
                        tuple |      167646 |     14.07 MB
                         list |        5116 |      6.03 MB
                        bytes |       77163 |      5.50 MB
                         code |       38540 |      5.32 MB
                         type |        5814 |      5.31 MB
                          set |        2039 |    959.21 KB
                      weakref |       10108 |    868.66 KB
                  abc.ABCMeta |         408 |    417.58 KB
            getset_descriptor |        5273 |    411.95 KB
                         cell |        7029 |    384.40 KB
          function (__init__) |        2519 |    354.23 KB
```

Answer (score 0):

oh boy, memory leaks are tough to handle

assuming this is linux system, maybe start with following to see if you can isolate the big memory areas (PID 15881)

```
sudo pmap 15881
```

let's say you identify a large area

```
..
0000558f3f556000 4507556K rw---   [ anon ]
..
```

to get the range

```
sudo cat /proc/15881/maps
```

eg

```
558f3f556000-559052762000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0     [heap]
```

use gdb to attach and dump that area to file

```
sudo gdb --pid 15881
(gdb) dump memory /tmp/mem.dump 0x558f3f556000 0x559052762000
```

glance thru' the /tmp/mem.dump file - check for frequently appearing parts

```
strings /tmp/mem.dump
```

afraid will need someone familiar with your python app to figure out

Comment: I'd suggest trying https://github.com/vmware/chap